# PySide2 QML - How to reference QML file within another QML file as component?

Tags: python, qt, qml, python-3.6, pyside2

I got 3 Files in the same folder:

form.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, os

from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QObject, QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
    qmlFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Main.qml')
    view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.abspath(qmlFile)))
    if view.status() == QQuickView.Error:
        sys.exit(-1)
    view.show()

    app.exec_()
    del view
```

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.10

Item {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    ListModel
    {
        id: myModel
        ListElement { type: "Dog"; age: 8 }
        ListElement { type: "Cat"; age: 5 }
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: myModel
        delegate: MyDelegate
    }
}
```

MyDelegate.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.10

Component {
    id: myDelegate
    Text { text: type + ", " + age }
}
```

Running the form.py should give me a window with a ListView and two elements in it. This code is taken from an [official tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#models) and changed so I can see how referencing of QML files within other QML files works. All I get is a white window, so I guess the delegate does not get loaded by the `Main.qml`.

The first letter of `MyDelegate.qml` is uppercase so the `Main.qml` should automatically load the delegate. I expect this behaviour because it is a solution from the question: [Include another QML file from a QML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168457/include-another-qml-file-from-a-qml-file#22170976)
and in many tutorials, including some for PyQt5, I saw them referencing other QML files like that.
If I copy the `Component {...}` part into the `Main.qml` and change the delegate reference in `ListView {...}` from `MyDelegate` to `myDelegate`, it works.

This problem appears with any QML node I want to outsource into a separate file.

Doesn't PySide2 support this feature, or do I have to do some magic in the `form.py` to let the `Main.qml` know that there is another QML file to load?

I installed the current wheel with

```
pip install --index-url=http://download.qt.io/snapshots/ci/pyside/5.11/latest/ pyside2 --trusted-host download.qt.io
```

from the [official wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/GettingStarted) on a Windows 10 64bit machine with Python 3.6 installed.

Comment: In your `ListView`, the delegate should be: `delegate: MyDelegate { }` - you are missing the braces `{ }`.

Comment: In your `MyDelegate.qml` the `Component { }` is unnecessary. It will be automatically added, when you assign it to a property of type `Component`

Comment: typo: change `delegate: MyDelegate` to `delegate: MyDelegate{}`

Comment: If `Component {  }` is unnecessary, what should I use instead in the `MyDelegate.qml`? I have to surround the `id:...` and `text:...` with something.

Comment: @AlfradS. only use `import QtQuick 2.10`   `Text { text: type + ", " + age }`

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok I see, the `id:...` is not necessary in such a simple file, because it would not be of use to the `Main.qml`, except I make it a property. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356278/qml-what-is-the-id-and-how-does-it-work).
Thank you.

Comment: Also, consider that a .qml file is already a Component, if you want to add a property to it, it would be `import QtQuick 2.10 Text {property Item innerItem: innerId text: type +", "+ age}`, consider that the component is a class so your new component inherits from the Text component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to derM and eyllanesc who pointed out that there is a typo in the reference of `MyDelegate.qml`. The reference should be with braces `delegate: MyDelegate {}`.

The correct form.py is now:

```
import QtQuick 2.10

Item {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    ListModel{
        id: myModel
        ListElement { type: "Dog"; age: 8 }
        ListElement { type: "Cat"; age: 5 }
    }
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: myModel
        delegate: MyDelegate {}
    }
}
```

It even works with `myModel` outsourced in a `MyModel.qml` and referenced as `model: MyModel {}`